# Why is it that when the same query is executed using ExecuteReader() in vb .net twice, it returns two very different response times?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Whenever a user clicks on `GetReport` button, there is a request to the server where SQL is formed in the back end and connection is established with Database. When the function `ExecuteReader()` is executed, it returns data at different time responses.

There are 12 servers in Production environment and the settings is such that when there is no response for more than 60 seconds from the back end, the connection is removed and hence blank screen appears on "UI".

In my code the SQL is formed and connection is established and when `ExecuteReader()`function is executed, it is returning data after the interval of 60 seconds where as per settings in the server, the connection is removed and hence leading to appearance of blank screen.

If the `ExecuteReader()` function returns data within 60 seconds, then the functionality works fine. The problem is only when the `ExecuteReader()` function does not retrieve data within 60 seconds.

Problem is that `ExecuteReader()` function returns data **within 2 seconds sometimes** for the same SQl and **sometimes takes 2 minutes** to retrieve data.

Please suggest why there is variation in returning data at different time intervals for the same query and how should I be proceeding in this situation as we are not able to increase the response time in production because of security issues.

Code is in `vb.net`

Comment: this is either a database or client query problem, on is better suited (with a lot more information) on dba.stackexchange.com - the other requires you to show us more (basically "any") code.

Comment: If execution time for the same exact query varies, it may be due to blocking, server load, cached data, synchronous stats update. Monitor execution on the database server.

Comment: Just to be sure that is not a code issue. Can you post the client code that prepares and runs your query.

Comment: As Dan suggested, it could be those reasons or even transaction lock (try executing query with no lock) or network. Also, since you need a report, prefer using Adapter than Reader. Reader is connection oriented and multiple round trips to rdbms will happen, putting load on Sql server as well

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself:

> how should I be proceeding in this situation as we are not able to increase the response time in production because of security issues.

There's nothing you can do

If, however, you do suddenly gain the permissions to modify the query that is being run, or reconfigure the resource provision of the production system, post back here with a screenshot of the execution plan and we can tell you any potential performance bottlenecks.

Dan's comment pretty much covers why a database query might be slow; usually a similar reason why YouTube is slower to buffer at 7pm - the parents got home from work at 6, the kids screamed at them for an hour ago wanting to go on YouTube while parent desperately tries to engage child in something more educational or physically active, parent finally gives in and wants some peace and quiet :) - resource provision/supply and demand in the entire chain between you and YouTube